# Foreach and push() with async await doesn't push the values

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, node-fetch

Here's my code:

```js
app.get("/bots/:id", async (req, res)=>{
 var bot = await Bots.findOne({id: req.params.id});
 if(!bot) return await res.send("not there");
 bot.desc = await marked(bot.desc);
 var user = req.user;
 bot.owner = [];
 await bot.owners.forEach(async (id)=>{
  await fetch(`${process.env.DOMAIN}/api/client/users/${id}`).then(r=>r.json()).then(async d=>{
  await bot.owner.push(d.tag);
 });
 });
 await console.log(bot.owner);
 await res.render('botpage.ejs', {user, bot});
})
```

App is express, fetch is node-fetch and I'm using ejs to render.
When I do console.log(bot.owner), it logs `[]` and not the array of `d.tag`s that I fetch.
Everything is fine except this, including my api and ejs page.
`process.env.DOMAIN` = https://discord.rovelstars.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach loop not wait. use for loop instead of foreach.

```
for(int i=0;i<bot.owners.length();i++){
 ....your task
}
```

or

```
for(var obj of bot.owners){
 ...your task
}
```

visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) for more details

Comment: it should be for....of instead for....in, for...in for object iteration